# jQuery widget development - can I use an MVC pattern?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, jquery-ui

I have been using knockoutjs and backbone to create a single page JavaScript application. I use backbone models and knockout view models, but I also have a lot of UI controls which I've used the jQuery UI widget factory to create.

My question is how to better structure the code in my jQuery widgets. Frameworks like knockout/backbone/ember make it easy to implement an MVC type pattern in the main app, but when it comes to widget development I end up having a big mush of code which output and manipulates DOM elements. I can still test this because jquery makes it easy to query the DOM but the code is pretty ugly. Ideally I'd like to have an MVC pattern in my widgets also.

Are there any libraries or frameworks out there designed to help out with this?

Comment: Great question! I've been looking for the same thing. Most of the time "widget" refers to simple ui elements that don't have to deal with complex data. And as far as I know jQuery UI's widget factory or Dojo's digit system are your best bet. For more complexity you've answered your own question: backbone/knockout/javascriptmvc/etc... If you find a better solution, please post it here as I'd love to hear what you come up with.

Comment: same doubt! first and foremost, i just can't get what EXACTLY do you (or anyone actually) mean by 'widget'...it just sounds cool...what it does? not much clear idea? define it - you get 100 definitions from 50 people...looking forward to some good answers - both about widget and the original question.

Comment: @ParthThakkar By widget I mean client side control, I said widget because that's what they called it in jQuery UI: there's a "widget" factory for building controls which I'm using. But yeah..widget, control..who cares

Comment: @nicholas I've got controls for browsing/selecting/searching hierarchical data, and controls for grouping selections. I wanted to create these a reusable controls and I suppose because these were fairly simple controls to start with, it made sense to use the jquery widget factory. As the complexity gains though, it would be great to use an MVC pattern but still be able to package it as a jquery control/widget.

Comment: I've just been making widgets with Backbone views so that I can keep it my code as MVC as possible. For example, here is a [time select widget that I recently made for a project](https://gist.github.com/8077a2a2e269f0ab7583). Seems to work well, but I've felt a little weird about it because I don't see many other examples of using BB Views in this way rather than for larger more complex views. Anybody else have ideas or experience why this might not be a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

In short:

- Keep widgets as much as a view part of the MVC as you can. Delegate the data out whenever possible.
- Don't write your widget with the predisposition of it being in your app. Treat the widget like a an island.
- Use Events to handle data passing out of the widget. Don't query for it.
- Use ["Tell, Don't ask"](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) pattern in widgets to keep the controller clean

Ideally, JQuery is the V part of the MVC pattern of your overall application. If widgets you have need to retain and return data when the user interacts with them, eventing is the way to go. Use the ["Tell, don't ask"](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) pattern of development in your widgets so that you don't have to query the state of your widgets to do something. This should clean up many of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I can help only with "V" part in MVC :)
Making DOM, I preffer OOCSS concept, where each class inherits parent`s properties, but You can integrate them together.

### OOCSS

```
<div class="mod"> 
    <b class="top"></b>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="bd"></div>
    </div>
    <b class="bottom"></b> 
</div>
```

https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki/Module

### jQuery UI

```
<div class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
  <div class="ui-widget-header"></div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

### Mixing OOCSS and jQuery UI

```
<div class="mod ui-widget ui-widget-content">
  <div class="top ui-widget-header"></div>
  <div class="inner ui-widget-content"></div>
  <div class="bottom ui-widget-footer ?"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks help, but the principles can be solved without them.  I'll typically build methods in my widget and/or private functions inside a self-executing anonymous function that give me the separation I'm looking for.  If the widget gets large, splitting the layers into different files can help, though this may make it more difficult to consume the final product.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on what you mean by jQuery widget. If your widget consists of just something small, like something that augments the functionality of HTML elements (i.e. autocomplete functionality to a textbox), then you're better off structuring your plugin nicely and [to test it](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit) properly. Just keep it as simple as possible. The MVC pattern would be an overhead there as people usually just like to take a single `js` file and reference it in their projects.

Instead, if you'd like to develop a Backbone style MVC app, [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/) might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've read your question in the following way, but I could be way off topic, so *caveat emptor*.

In terms of breaking out your code into independent units of code, you may want to consider using [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) to pull them all back in again. Personally, I'm not a fan of the syntax, but from a pragmatic point of view, maybe this would be helpful, as if you do decide to break up your huge mongo file into discrete reusable units, you will probably see a lot of benefits from isolating units of functionality into independent files and having an easy way to make sure your dependencies are loaded up in the right order.

As an aside, you may be interested in checking out [PureMVCJS](http://puremvc.org/component/option,com_frontpage/Itemid,1/) as an organisational principle once you have dependency resolution pinned down- it provides the means, like many other MVC frameworks, of breaking out your code into resuable layers or vertical slices. Out of the box, it is independent of any DOM or OOP abstraction library, which, depending on what you're trying to achieve, be a boon (yay- I can change my DOM abstraction library without breaking my services) or a pain (I've gotta write an integration layer between my DOM library and PureMvc views), but I've found it useful (then again, I may be biased, because, in the spirit of full disclosure, I was one of the authors of the port).

Anyhow, hope this helps.